# Projection problem from gdal2tiles.py to R Leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet, gdal, amazon-linux-2, gdal2tiles.py

I do have a projection problem when making tiles with GDAL command and using the same for Leaflet in R. The steps I am following are:

1. I save the Tiff in QGIs with the following configuration:

[image]

2. In Centos Amazon Linux 2 and GDAL I Run the following command:

   gdal2tiles.py --s_srs EPSG:3857-WGS84  usa_tif.tif tiles
3. After generating the tiles I get an openlayer.html which looks ok:

[image]

4. But when I add the file into Leafet in R I get the following:
   [image]

Maybe you have an idea what is happening?

When I run:

```
 which gdalinfo; gdalinfo --version
```

I get:

```
GDAL 3.2.1, released 2020/12/29
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just a configuration in the Leaflet R code to:

```
tms = TRUE

addTiles(urlTemplate = "usa_tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", group = "USA GDP", options = tileOptions(opacity = 0.6, tms = TRUE)) %>%
```